# Extract data from xml

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, xquery-sql

i came to know that the below sql can be used to extract data from xml

```
--XML DATA SAMPLE        
DECLARE @xmlvar xml      
SET @xmlvar='      
<NewDataSet>      
  <param>      
    <SearchField>JID</SearchField>      
    <FilterCondition>%</FilterCondition>      
    <ConditionData>4000</ConditionData>      
    <MatchCase>0</MatchCase>      
    <Table>MyTableName</Table>      
  </param>      
  <param>      
    <SearchField>Specialist</SearchField>      
    <FilterCondition>=</FilterCondition>      
    <ConditionData>Nigel Graham</ConditionData>      
    <MatchCase>0</MatchCase>      
    <Table>MyTableName</Table>      
  </param>      
</NewDataSet>'  

SELECT  A.B.value('(SearchField)[1]', 'VARCHAR(255)' ) SearchField,
A.B.value('(FilterCondition)[1]', 'VARCHAR(25)' ) Operator,
A.B.value('(ConditionData)[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)' ) ConditionData,
A.B.value('(MatchCase)[1]', 'BIT' ) MatchCase,
A.B.value('(Table)[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)' ) TableName
FROM    @WhereClause_XML.nodes('/NewDataSet/param') A(B)
```

the above xml is working but i am not familiar with the above type of sql. so please tell me
what is the meaning of (FilterCondition)[1] or (ConditionData)[1]
why bracket [1] why not bracket [0] or [2].

please explain me how above xml works. thanks

Comment: why not talk to the person who gave you this code and have them explain it to you?

Comment: yes i asked but got no answer....if u know then plzz help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [value()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178030.aspx) function returns one value from your XML so the XPath used must point to one specific node. `[1]` in `(SearchField)[1]` means that you want the value from the first occurrence of `SearchField` in the XML. `[2]` would then of course give you the second occurrence. Without `[1]` you are asking for all occurrences of `SearchField`.

**Update:** Sample code:

```
declare @x xml = 
'<root>
  <item>1</item>
  <item>2</item>
</root>'

select @x.value('(root/item)[1]', 'int') as One,
       @x.value('(root/item)[2]', 'int') as Two
```

Result:

```
One         Two
----------- -----------
1           2
```

Comment: can u please show me some more usage of similar data extraction from xml. u said -- 1 means that you want the value from the first occurrence of SearchField in the XML. [2] would then of course give you the second occurrence. Without [1] you are asking for all occurrences of SearchField. come with some sample code where u use [1] and [2] and without [1]. so i can issue ur code in sql server and then try to understand how things work. thanks

Comment: @Thomas You can have a look at the questions and answers tagged with xquery-sql. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xquery-sql

Comment: thanks sure i will visit link but it would be better if provide 2 or 3 small sample for [1] or [2]. if possible please give me sample query

Comment: @Thomas added a sample to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the `FROM` clause here:

```
FROM @WhereClause_XML.nodes('/NewDataSet/param') A(B)
```

creates a "pseudo table" of XML fragments - it enumerates all XML nodes `<NewDataSet>/<param>` and creates that pseudo table (called `A`) with a pseudo column `B` of type `XML`.

These columns will contain the values of `<param>` - and the `SELECT` is reaching into these XML nodes

```
SELECT A.B.value('(SearchField)[1]', 'VARCHAR(255)' ) SearchField
```

here, from the `<param>` node, the first `<SearchField>` XML element value is retrieved and returned as a column called `SearchField` of type `VARCHAR(255)`.

From the looks of your code, each of the `<param>` node probably looks something like:

```
<param>
    <SearchField>......</SearchField>
    <FilterCondition>....</FilterCondition>
    <ConditionData>....</ConditionData>
    <MatchCase>....</MatchCase>
    <Table>....</Table>
</param>
```

and all those values are extracted into columns of your `SELECT` statement.